# I'm having trouble trying to run the HandBrakeCLI with php for some reason

Tags: php, shell, scripting, exec, command-line-interface

This simple script:

```
<?php
        $cmd='./HandBrakeCLI -i ./a.flv -o ./ab.mkv';
        echo exec($cmd.'&');
?>
```

outputs:
Encoding: task 1 of 1, 0.46 %

Or a similarly low percentage and produces no real output file.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236267/get-php-to-update-with-every-line-returned-from-a-shell-command) might be useful for your problem.